# how can ArrayList of type Int32 can be bigger than List of type Int32

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have an assignment which consists in explaining the following results when creating instances of generic types `ArrayList` and `List`.

```
ArrayList de Int32 = 280 ns ; 1.603.604 bytes   
List<Int32> = 59 ns ; 408.224 bytes 
ArrayList de String = 77 ns ; 408.224 bytes
List<String> = 74 ns ; 408.224 bytes
```

I've spent a fairly big amount of time trying to figure this out, and another big amount of time trying to find something on the internet, and nothing.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I guess boxing makes this change. Post the code so that we can see what does your tests do.

Comment: `ArrayList` is not a generic type. So with valuetype items like Int32, boxing will be a big influence on runtimes.

Comment: I don't have the code, the only thing given was that output...

Comment: I really don't understand why someone downvoted the question. While it may be a duplicate it is very hard for the person who asks it to know that it is a duplicate. It can even be argued that it is different enough to not be considered duplicate of the proposed question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is OK to ask for the solution of an assignment. On the other hand I think the assignment is stupid since you either read somewhere about the difference and how generics in .NET work or did not so I guess I will answer anyway.

ArrayList is not generic which means it holds an array of objects. Every int should be boxed in an object which adds like 12 bytes (I think the overhead of an object was 12 bytes but I may be off by a few bytes) to the actual 4 bytes data. This is the memory cost of wrapping an int in an object. There is also CPU time cost to do the wrapping and unwrapping. On the other hand List or any value type is specialized. This means that the CLR generates a special version of the list for ints. The internal array is an array of int instead of objects so no additional memory is lost for the data. The time also improves since no boxing and unboxing is performed. Note that the additional objects put pressure on the GC which must collect them at some point.

For string there is no penalty because strings are reference types so they basically work the same way as objects do. They already contain the 12 bytes of overhead. There may be some little CPU overhead from checking the types when casting but expensive boxing is not performed. This is why there is no significant difference in performance and memory between the generic list and the ArrayList

Also worth noting is that this method is not how generics work in all languages. For example Java is quite different so be sure to check if your knowledge applies if you use some non-.NET technology.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this assignment was really confusing...

Comment: In 64 bit systems, the object wrapper should occupy 16 bytes ( 8 for the type pointer, which points to `System.Object`, and 8 for the sync block pointer). Add the integer's 32 bits. Add the array's pointer to the boxed int. That's 28 bytes. So, a `List<int>` will require 4 bytes for each integer, whereas an `ArrayList` will require 28 bytes.

Comment: @dcastro seems like the tests are on 32 bit since the ArrayList version takes just 4 times the space.

Comment: @Stilgar Yeah, on 32 bit systems a boxed int plus its pointer would occupy 16 bytes (4 for the type pointer, 4 for the sync block pointer, 4 for the actual int, 4 for the pointer to the boxed int), which is 4 times the size of an unboxed integer.